# How to check if text exist inside class using Selenium and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium. I like to verify if a specific class contains a text snippet in JavaScript.

I have following HTML:

```
<div class="product-small">
   <div class="data">
      <p>This is some Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="product-small">
   <div class="data">
      <p>This is some Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
...
```

The above class are available multiple times on the page, so i have to iterate the "product-small" class to check if all 12 classes contains the text "some". If one of the 12 elements with that "product-small" class does not contain the text "some", the test will fail.

I thought something like this:

```
const cars = driver.findElements(By.className('product-small'));
    cars.forEach(function (element) {
        // Check if element contains "some" inside class "data"
        // If element does not contain "some", test will fail
    });
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution would be to collect the elements using the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) and probe the length, if it equals to **12** then mark it as **Pass** else mark it as **Fail**

```
const cars = driver.findElements(By.xpath("div[@class='product-small']//p[contains(., 'some')]"));
```